# How can I share a directory between Azure App Service slots?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service with two slots. Is it possible to have these slots share a directory via Path Mappings or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible. You should use Azure Storage for it.

Comment: That was what I was thinking until I saw that you couldn't add blob storage as a mapped path.

Comment: not sure what you need, but you should be able to access the storage account from both slots. For a real shared directory, you should use Azure Storage Files, but you won't be able to map it to the VM that hosts your App Service, since it's a shared environment