# I have an azure app service with two slots. Do they share the same temp folder path?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I have a an Azure app service with two slots (live and staging) and have an issue with IronPDF, which I have been told could be down to my app service's slots sharing the same temp folder.

Does anyone know if they do share the same one. I understand they would be on the same Virtual Machine. So my assumption is yes. But then would that mean that restarting either slot would clear it for both?

Just want to confirm if this is the issue.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

App service slots do not share storage, as per [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/19042/azure-app-service-shared-storage-between-deploymen.html) of a MS employee on the MS forum.

> To answer you initial question, app service slots do not share storage. A slot can be considered as a separate VM instance within your app service plan. A clear indicator of this is the fact you can't use slots for Shared VM SKUs.

By the way:

> ... and have an issue with IronPDF ...

what is the issue you are having?

Comment: Thank you for your help that at least answers that. Make sense that they don't.

Comment: The issue with IronPdf is that it randomly gets stuck when rendering a pdf. All standard calls to my api work. But any involving rendering a pdf fail. The IronPdf team suggest upgrading, as it appears to be known, but I am hesitant, as of when checking it had very few downloads and I want to know a bit more as to why this issue is happening, before upgrading past what appears to be the most stable version. They also suggested that if it shared the same temp folder it would cause issues on older version. Hence, why it led me to question if the two slots were the reason behind this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think two different slots share the path / folder. Another SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583863/how-can-i-share-a-directory-between-azure-app-service-slots)

When you create a slot (ex: staging), it will not share the same Virtual Machine that the **production** slot use. Internally, within App Service Plan, a separate instance will be allocated for the staging slot. You can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/19042/azure-app-service-shared-storage-between-deploymen.html)

You can also see the section "What happens during a swap" which talks about Source Slot instances etc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#what-happens-during-a-swap)

Comment: Thank you for help and the links.